# How to pass two or more lists by using python and store it to mysql database

Tags: python, mysql

```
period = ['January 2000', 'February 2000', 'March 2000', 'April 2000' ]
total = ['623,794', '605,936', '667,027', '635,767']
mydb=mysql.connector.connect(host="localhost",user="root",passwd="")
mycursor=mydb.cursor()
mycursor.execute("create database if not exists scrap")
mycursor.execute("use scrap")
mycursor.execute("drop table if  exists DomesticPassenger_DeparturesPerformed_Flights")
sql = """create table DomesticPassenger_DeparturesPerformed_Flights(
period varchar(100) not null,
total varchar(100) not null
)"""
mycursor.execute(sql)    
for k,l in period,total:  
 mycursor.execute(
        "insert into DomesticPassenger_DeparturesPerformed_Flights(period,total) VALUES (%s,%s)" % (k,l))
        mydb.commit()
```

"For period and total there are large amount of data I have only added few  data for easy understanding"

Comment: Period and total are lists

Comment: Where is that list and what should be the resulting SQL?

Comment: Can you give more specific details on your question? Please elaborate a little

Comment: I want to export the lists from python to mysql database @KlausD

Comment: Please add the relevant information to the question itself, not a comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
period = ['January 2000', 'February 2000', 'March 2000', 'April 2000' ]
total = ['623,794', '605,936', '667,027', '635,767']
mydb=mysql.connector.connect(host="localhost",user="root",passwd="")
mycursor=mydb.cursor()
mycursor.execute("create database if not exists scrap")
mycursor.execute("use scrap")
mycursor.execute("drop table if  exists DomesticPassenger_DeparturesPerformed_Flights")
sql = """create table DomesticPassenger_DeparturesPerformed_Flights(
period varchar(100) not null,
total varchar(100) not null
)"""
mycursor.execute(sql)
for k, l in zip(period,total):
    mycursor.execute("insert into DomesticPassenger_DeparturesPerformed_Flights(period,total) values (%s,%s)",(k,l))
    mydb.commit()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following code block :

```
import mysql.connector
from mysql.connector import Error

def insFlights(i_val):
        try:
                mydb = mysql.connector.connect(host='localhost', database='mydbname', user='myschema', password='mypwd')
                mycursor = mydb.cursor()

                sql = "insert into DomesticPassenger_DeparturesPerformed_Flights(period,total) values (%s,%s)"
                mycursor.execute(sql, val)

                mydb.commit()
                print("Records inserted successfully")

        except mysql.connector.Error as error:
                print("Failed to insert into the table {}".format(error))                

i_val = [
  ('January 2000','623,794'), 
  ('February 2000', '605,936'),
  ( 'March 2000', '667,027'),
  ( 'April 2000', '635,767')
]

insFlights(i_val)
```

P.S. you can replace `execute` with `executemany` for large set of data

Comment: How to pass this type of lists `period = ['January 2000', 'February 2000', 'March 2000', 'April 2000'] total = ['623,794', '605,936', '667,027', '635,767']`

Comment: For few data this is ok I have a large amount data in a list we cannot type all the time right ? any way to pass large set of data

Comment: you can replace execute with executemany for large set of data @MonikRaj